# Loaded product missing media_gallery attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am loading a product like so:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'MyStockCode');
```

Then I try to get the images using:

```
$existingGallery = $product->getMediaGallery('images');
```

but it comes back with a null value. When inspecting `_data` against `$product` the `media_gallery` attribute is missing.

From all the references I have read, this is how to load the images against a product but this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Notes:

I can see the images in the admin area against that product so they are definitely there.

I am doing this in the admin area, not frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load by attribute give you collection so Recommendation is load product via its id So it will give you whole product object.

Fetch product id from $product object which you have already load and then load with product id.

```
$product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(product id);
```

then `$product->getMediaGalleryImages()` give you all product images

Answer (score 0):

try below code for getting product Image

```
$product->getImageUrl();
```

Comment: That is not the same as returning a collection of images.